# basic help using hmm to clasify a sequence

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, hidden-markov-models

I am very new to matlab, hidden markov model and machine learning, and am trying to classify a given sequence of signals. Please let me know if the approach I have followed is correct:

1. create a N by N transition matrix and fill with random values which sum to 1for each row. (N will be the number of states)
2. create a N by M emission/observation matrix and fill with random values which sum to 1 for each row
3. convert different instances of the sequence (i.e each instance will be saying the word 'hello' ) into one long stream and feed each stream to the hmm train function such that:

   new_transition_matrix old_transition_matrix = hmmtrain(sequence,old_transition_matrix,old_emission_matrix)
4. give the final transition and emission matrix to hmm decode with an unknown sequence to give the probability
   i.e `[posterior_states logrithmic_probability] = hmmdecode( sequence, final_transition_matrix,final_emission_matris)`

Comment: Have U done it, I also  need help regarding HMM. Which toolbox U have used?

Comment: Like the answer stated below, i used Murphys toolbox but used HMM with Gaussian outputs. you can see the tutorial here http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/HMM/hmm_usage.html

Comment: I'v seen this, I'v some queries regarding HMM, is HMM generates a trained file like `.xml` in Neural networks? I want to train trajectories with HMM, having X,Y,Z co-ordinates, What will be sequences as I think my states are every new row of changing state position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** and **2.** are correct. You have to be careful that your initial transition and emission matrices are not completely uniform, they should be slightly randomized for the [training](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm) to work.

**3.** I would just feed in the 'Hello' sequences separately rather than concatenating them to form a single long sequence.

Let's say this is the sequence for Hello:  `[1,0,1,1,0,0]`. If you form one long sequence from 3 'Hello' sequences, you would get:

`data = [1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0]`

This is not ideal, instead you should feed the sequences in separately like:

`data = [1,0,1,1,0,0; 1,0,1,1,0,0; 1,0,1,1,0,0]`.

Since you are using MatLab, I would recommend using the [HMM toolbox](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/HMM/hmm_usage.html) by Murphy. It has a demo on how you can train an HMM with multiple observation sequences:

```
M = 3;
N  = 2;

% "true" parameters
prior0 = normalise(rand(N ,1));
transmat0 = mk_stochastic(rand(N ,N ));
obsmat0 = mk_stochastic(rand(N ,M));

% training data: a 5*6 matrix, e.g. 5 different 'Hello' sequences of length 6
number_of_seq = 5;
seq_len= 6;
data = dhmm_sample(prior0, transmat0, obsmat0, number_of_seq, seq_len);

% initial guess of parameters
prior1 = normalise(rand(N ,1));
transmat1 = mk_stochastic(rand(N ,N ));
obsmat1 = mk_stochastic(rand(N ,M));

% improve guess of parameters using EM
[LL, prior2, transmat2, obsmat2] = dhmm_em(data, prior1, transmat1, obsmat1, 'max_iter', 5);
LL
```

**4.** What you say is correct, below is how you calculate the log probaility in the HMM toolbox:

```
% use model to compute log[P(Obs|model)]
loglik = dhmm_logprob(data, prior2, transmat2, obsmat2)
```

**Finally:** Have a look at this [paper by Rabiner](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs4758/2012sp/materials/hmm_paper_rabiner.pdf) on how the mathematics work if anything is unclear.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly is prior0? And thanks for the answer. really appreciated.

Comment: You actually do not need it in your case. `prior0`, `transmat0` and `obsmat0` are used in data generation step. They represent the real model (as generated by the machine learner) so that after training the system, the experimenter can compare the learned parameters `prior2`, `transmat2` and `obsmat2`, to those that actually created the data.  `prior0` in specific gives the probability of the system being in a state in the very beginning, e.g. 'does the model start at state1 or state2?'

Comment: thanks a lot. But I'm looking at 'HMMs with mixture of Gaussians outputs' right now since I require vector, but I am having trouble understanding this line "Now let use fit a mixture of M=2 Gaussians ". What exactly does M represent?  I am studying gaussian right now but I cant figure out what M does.

Comment: In a typical MoG application, sample data are thought of
as originating from various possible sources (in your case M), and the data from each particular source is modelled by a Gaussian. Google and Wikipedia should help a lot in this. For example this [link](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dasgupta/papers/mog.pdf).

Comment: @Zhubarb I'm bit bit confusing in `hmmtrain` or training process of HMM, however I want to know if some `.xml` generated for track past record or generating the probabilities at run time, when specifically using EM training?